# For loop - Struct with lifetime 'a cannot borrow as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust, lifetime-scoping

I have a struct which maps ids to indices and vice versa.

```
struct IdMapping<'a> {
    external_2_internal: HashMap<&'a str, usize>,
    internal_2_external: HashMap<usize, String>,
}

impl<'a> IdMapping<'a> {
    fn new() -> IdMapping<'a> {
        IdMapping {
            external_2_internal: HashMap::new(),
            internal_2_external: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn insert(&'a mut self, internal: usize, external: String) {
        self.internal_2_external.insert(internal, external);
        let mapped_external = self.internal_2_external.get(&internal).unwrap();
        self.external_2_internal.insert(mapped_external, internal);
    }
}
```

If I am using this structure the following way

```
fn map_ids<'a>(ids: Vec<String>) -> IdMapping<'a> {
    let mut mapping = IdMapping::new();

    for (i, id) in ids.iter().enumerate() {
        mapping.insert(i, id.clone());
    }

    mapping
}
```

I receive the following compiler error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `mapping` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:28:9
   |
24 | fn map_ids<'a>(ids: Vec<String>) -> IdMapping<'a> {
   |            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
28 |         mapping.insert(i, id.clone());
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `mapping` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
...
31 |     mapping
   |     ------- returning this value requires that `mapping` is borrowed for `'a`
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a681d31d0c174b0174f85e0a4312ee96)

Why can't I mutably borrow the mapping for its `insert` method each iteration of the loop? How should I implement this use case?

Comment: I am very sorry about that mistake. I tried to remove the references to my problem domain to make it more accesible.

I have update the example

Comment: Thanks for updating! And its more for your benefit than mine since good questions will hopefully get you good, prompt answers.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the self reference in your struct.

Let's first look at whether this is theoretically sound (assuming we're writing unsafe code):

1. `HashMap` uses a flat array (quadratic probing), so objects in the HashMap aren't address stable under insertion of a new element.  This means that an insertion into `internal_2_external` may move the existing `String`s around in memory.
2. `String` stores its content in a separate heap allocation, the heap allocation remains at the same location.  So even if the `String` is moved around, a `&str` referencing it will remain pointing to valid memory.

So this would actually work if implemented in unsafe code.

While it's logically sound to do those operations, the type system is unable to recognise that you can move a `String` while keeping borrowed ranges of it valid.  This means that if you borrow a `&str` from a `String`, the type system will prevent you from doing any mutation operation on your `String`, including moving it.  As such, you can't do any mutation operation on the hash map either, giving rise to your error.

I can see two safe ways to work around this:

- Make `external_2_internal` keep its own copy of the strings, i.e. use`HashMap<String, usize>`.
- Keep the strings in a separate `Vec`:

```
struct IdMapping {
    strings: Vec<String>,
    external_2_internal: HashMap<usize /* index */, usize>,
    internal_2_external: HashMap<usize, usize /* index */>,
}
```

Alternatively you could work with unsafe code, if you don't want to change the layout of your struct.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have a Java background where this pattern doesn't impose any problems and I was trying to wrap my head around this for a while now. I will try using the vector approach.